# Setting up a CRON JOB based on receiving email on mail server

Tags: php, email, cron

Is there any way to get notified when a new email is received in my mail server and setting up a cron job based on the notification?

For example, say my mail server is xxx.com. someone@gmai.com send a mail to myacc@xxx.com at 7pm  while I am not at my office. I want to reply to that mail using php from my web server associated with the mail server.

I want to run a php script periodically which will check for new email received on the mail server and if a new email is received, acquiring information like sender's email etc, I want to reply to that email using another php script. Is it possible?

Hope I am able to describe it clearly. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Cron jobs run at given times / intervals, not in response to external stimuli. On the face of it cron is not the right solution, but to be sure, you need to provide more info - so in short, this is not a programming question suitable for SO.

Comment: you want to pipe the mail from the mailserver to a php script. actully cronjob and [imap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) may be better

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have edited the post. Hope it is more elaborate now. @John3136

Comment: Presumably your mail server doesn't support an out of office reply?  A cron could be setup to monitor your mailbox on the file server, parse it for new entries and generate a boilerplate response, but I have to think for any common mail servers this problem has already been solved.  What server, OS, etc are you using?

Comment: may be, I am not sure about what you are talking about though. @Dagon

Comment: well get your google shoes on then :-) I would pipe it if i could, 2nd choice would be imap - your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This honestly sounds like a job for the PHP [IMAP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). Set up a cron job to run a PHP script that logs into the mailbox; you can then use the [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send a response to any mails that you determine need to be handled.